# mediaelement.js: Audio doesn't play automatically

Tags: html5-audio, mediaelement.js

Recently I checked my homepage on a mobile and noticed that the audio doesn't start to play automatically:
http://www.ulrichbangert.de/heimat/mediaelement/2014-03-29_Harz_Stabkirche_Glockenspiel.php
Also I wasn't able to start the audio by touching the play button.
I'm using the player mediaelement.jf
My mobile is Samsung Ace 3. Any ideas how to fix this problem?
Best regards - Ulrich

Comment: It plays for me on iOS 7.1 after I hit play.

Comment: Hallo idbehold, yes, it works. In the meantime I've made the player responsive and now there is some space to the edge of the screen. Thus it's easier to hit the play button. Any ideas how to make the audio start automatically?

Comment: You cannot start any `audio`/`video` on iOS without direct physical user interaction. The best you can do is call `.play()` on your `audio`/`video` as soon as a `touchstart` event fires anywhere inside the page. And only then will the browser actually attempt to load the media.